# What are R stringr alternatives to following Matlab string manipulations using patterns?

Tags: r, matlab, stringr

I am new to R and trying to find alternatives to following Matlab string manipulations in R (preferably using stringr and not pure regex). Can someone please help.

```
itrDay - a numeric iterator

VariableNames - a string vector (column names from a table)
```

```
extractBefore(VariableNames,"_"+itrDay+textBoundary)
contains(VariableNames,["_"+digitsPattern+"min_bouts_","_"+digitsPattern+"min_freq_"])
```

This is what I have written now. But these are incomplete and not the same as Matlab expressions above

```
# how I can bring Matlab textBoundary to here
str_remove(VariableNames,str_c("_",itrDay)) 
# is this ok?
str_detect(VariableNames,c(str_c("_","\\d+","min_bouts_"),str_c("_","\\d+","min_freq_")))
```

Inputs:

```
itrDay=2
VariableNames=["Walk_2","Walk_2min_bouts_2","Lie_2","Lie_2min_bouts_2"]
VariableNames2=["Leisure_Sit_3min_bouts_TL","Leisure_Sit_min_bouts_TL","Leisure_Move_10min_freq_H","Leisure_Move_min_freq_H"]
```

Outputs (Matlab):

```
extractBefore(VariableNames,"_"+itrDay+textBoundary)

"Walk"    "Walk_2min_bouts"    "Lie"    "Lie_2min_bouts"

contains(VariableNames2,["_"+digitsPattern+"min_bouts_","_"+digitsPattern+"min_freq_"])
1   0   1   0
```

Output (R)

```
str_remove(VariableNames,str_c("_",itrDay))
"Walk"   "Walkmin_bouts_2"     "Lie"     "Liemin_bouts_2" 
str_detect(VariableNames2,c(str_c("_","\\d+","min_bouts_"),str_c("_","\\d+","min_freq_")))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Please share an input together with an expected output.

Comment: @Martin added input/output examples showing my R code is not correct

Comment: Why does MatLab return `1   0   1   0` instead of `0 1 0 1`? The pattern is present in the second and the fourth string but not in the first and third. Therefore I expect `0 1 0 1`.

Comment: The pattern (" _"+digitsPattern+"min_bouts_") matches the first string "Leisure_Sit_3min_bouts_TL" isn't it? Similarly the other pattern ("_"+digitsPattern+"min_freq_") matches the third string "Leisure_Move_10min_freq_H".

Comment: For some reason underscores in above comment are removed !

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, you could use

```r
library(stringr)

itrDay <- 2
VariableNames <- c("Walk_2","Walk_2min_bouts_2","Lie_2","Lie_2min_bouts_2")

pattern <- paste0("(_", itrDay, ")$")

str_remove(VariableNames, pattern)
#> [1] "Walk"            "Walk_2min_bouts" "Lie"             "Lie_2min_bouts"
```

We create a `pattern` out of `itrDay` and use it as a regular expression. The pattern `"(_2)$"` removes `_2` at the end of each string.

```r
VariableNames2 <- str_remove(VariableNames, pattern)

str_detect(VariableNames2, "_\\d+min_(bouts|freq)")
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Note: Since we removed `_2` in the first step, we changed the search pattern for step two and removed the last `_`.

Comment: Thanks v much. Will this work work if itrDay is two or three digits number also?